# conflict in slf4j dependency

Tags: spring-boot, maven, slf4j

I`m using spring boot 2.6.6 and logback and slf4j. when I run application in my local computer in IntellijA IDE using "Run configuration", application starts normally. but when I build app with goal "clean package" and then run with command line "java -jar myApp.war" the following error occures:

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener : org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:456)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:438)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:431)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:263)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:241)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
        at com.fanap.kidzy.vidzy.VidzyApplication.main(VidzyApplication.java:16)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V
        at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(ResolvableType.java:1088)
        at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(ResolvableType.java:1074)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Bindable.mapOf(Bindable.java:267)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.<clinit>(LoggingApplicationListener.java:98)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:452)
        ... 15 more
```

I analyzed the pom with "dependency analyzer" plugin but slf4j 1.7.6 or 1.6 not exists!
[image]

Comment: Consider posting the relevant parts of your pom. Sounds like maybe a version mismatch.

Comment: I add <scope>provided</scope> to my dependency and problem solved.